# Finite almost surely implies integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.

If a random variable $X$ satisfies $\mathbb{P}[X<\infty]=1$ (which means $X$ is finite almost surely, doesn't it?) then $\mathbb{E}[X]<\infty$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.
Take $P(X=2^n)=2^{-n}$.
Then $P(X<\infty)=1$ and $E(X)=\infty$.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to give additional conditions under the statement in the question will be true?

Comment: @seek The best condition I can think of is .... that $\Bbb E[X]<\infty$.

Comment: why is $\mathbb{P}(X<\infty)=1$? The Borel-Cantelli Lemma only implies that $\mathbb{P}(X=2^{n} i.o.)=0$, and I don't know what to do next.