# Why does $\mathrm{E}[|X|] < \infty$ imply $\mathrm{P}[X < \infty] = 1$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I found this one

[Finite almost surely implies integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243230/finite-almost-surely-implies-integrable)

which shows that $X$ finite a.s. does not imply $X$ integrable...

But how can I show that the converse is true?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If $P[X=\infty]>0$ then $E[|X|]=E[|X|\cdot 1_{X<\infty}] + E[\infty\cdot 1_{X=\infty}]\geq \infty\cdot P[X=\infty]=\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $S_{n}=\{\omega\in \Omega: |X(\omega)|\geq n\}$ and $S=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}S_{n}$, then $P(S)\leq P(S_{n})\leq n^{-1}E[|X|]\rightarrow 0$, so $P(S)=0$. Then $P[|X|<\infty]=1-P(S)=1$. Since $P[|X|<\infty] \leq P[X<\infty]$, now we have $P[X<\infty] = 1$.

Comment: So you say, basically, "use Markov's inequality"?

Comment: Yes, Markov's inequality takes place for that $P(S_{n})\leq n^{-1}E[|X|]$.